# HTML5 inline video ignores z-index

Tags: css, html5-video, z-index

I have an inline HTML5 video that's ignoring `z-index` and is being displayed over a higher positioned element. I've tried all the solutions and advice I could find, like explicitly positioning the elements and setting `z-index`, but to no avail.

The simplified structure goes like so:

```
<div class="content">
 <div class="row 1">
  <bunch of other divs>
   <div class="product_socials_wrapper">
    links
   </div>
  </bunch of other divs>
 </div>
 <div class="row 2">
  <bunch of other divs>
   <video>
   </video>
  </bunch of other divs>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
.product_socials_wrapper {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 999;
}
.row2 .column .column-inner {
 z-index: 1;
}
```

The `.product_socials_wrapper` div is always displayed floating on the left above all other elements, except the `<video>` one. It has no problem floating above even the video's immediate parent wrapper.
This is only visible at widths where the `<video>` is close enough to the left to overlap with the `.product_socials_wrapper` div, like 1300px wide. Moreover, if I replace the video with, say, an image, without changing any other code, the problem disappears. So my guess it's not a stacking mistake in the code.

You can see this in Chrome and Firefox [here](https://slimbyapriori.global/collection/slim-black-gold-toothbrush/).
This is a live site built with WordPress and WPBakery Page Builder.
The `.product_socials_wrapper` is part of the theme, so I don't have much control over its HTML.
The `<video>` tag is inserted manually into WPBakery builder via its 'raw code' widget, so I can tinker with it at will, as well as with CSS, albeit to no avail so far.

Any pointers in the right direction greatly appreciated.

Comment: In https://slimbyapriori.global/media/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer.min.css, `.vc_row.vc_row-flex > .vc_column_container > .vc_column-inner` has a z-index of "1". Switching this to "0" made the overlap problem go away.

Comment: Wow! The one thing that didn't occur to me. Thank you @MarkHillard ! Please post this as an answer so I can upvote it and mark this as solved.
Any chance you know why this '1' overlaps the '999' and why this happens only with the video and doesn't affect images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.vc_row.vc_row-flex > .vc_column_container > .vc_column-inner {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

This fixes the overlap problem. My guess is that the fixed position of the social buttons takes it out of the normal stacking context, so z-index wasn't working like you expected. It's hard to tell because I'm sure the CMS you're using auto-generates HTML and CSS for certain things.

Comment: I doubt it's WordPress. Must be the theme or WPBakery Page Builder. Still, it's weird that this happens with the video, but doesn't happen with an image. And the actual .vc-column-inner and all its children up to the `<video>` tag don't overlap the social buttons...